# Python multithreading call to C not getting around global interpreter lock (GIL)

Tags: python, multithreading, ctypes, gil

I'm trying to program a raspberry pi 3 camera ("picamera") to improve its acquisition characteristics. The picamera is very precise at acquiring frames up to 90Hz (GPU has independent clock), but the raspberry pi - and the linux OS (jessy) - hangs up or freezes periodically while saving to disk. When the pi freezes, the frames that come from the camera are lost into the ether. I don't know why the pi freezes, but I assume the bandwidth or thread tasks are being bottle-necked somewhere.

So I thought that writing python code to save the frames to memory - and then passing a memory pointer to C code which will **independently** (and on its own time) save the data to disk - will overcome the freezing issue. I used  a ctypes based python call to send the memory pointer of the python array to C.

Here's the rough layout:

```
picamera (python) -------------- ongoing picamera processing...
                 \
                  -> python thread -> call C-based saving (dll/ctypes)
```

And here's some snipets of the code (the picamera has many thousands of lines of code):

```
#Main python code to initialize thread call to python function:
...    
self.image_stack_0=((ct.c_char*int(self.n_pixels)**2*3))) #init memory buffer
t = threading.Thread(target=self.c_saving)  #call python routine on 2nd thread
...

#3-line python routine being called above
def c_saving(self):
   ''' Code to save data to disk using C while ongoing acquisition '''
    _sum = ct.CDLL('/home/pi/murphylab_picam/save_c.so')
    _sum.save_c.argtype = (ct.POINTER(ct.c_int32), ct.POINTER(ct.c_int32), ct.POINTER(ct.c_char), ct.POINTER(ct.c_char))
    _sum.save_c(self.save_block, self.frame_ctr, self.image_stack_0, self.image_stack_1)
```

So the code works great, but writes to disk continue to cause periodic (though less serious) hangups/freezes to the python frame acquisitions.

I have a minimal understanding of the global-interpreter-lock (GIL), but it seems that simply calling a python thread - which then calls C-code - does not result in C-code running **independently on a 2nd core** (the raspberry pi 3 has 4 cores).

Is there a way to ensure that the C module being called (which simply tracks the frame buffer array and writes it periodically) will run on a 2nd core?  Multiprocessing might be a solution, but the code is already complicated and I'm not sure how to share memory addresses across cores.

Thanks for the read.

EDIT: Thanks for the comments. I commonly use multiprocessing on my workstation, but the problem here is I need to spawn a parallel process after initializing and running python code. As far as I know multiprocessing calls lock the python code while the respective functions are run (albeit on different cores).

But is a thread call followed by a multiprocessing call which then calls the C-code possible? Something like this:

```
picamera (python) -------------- ongoing picamera processing...
                     \
                      -> py thread -> py multiprocessing call ->  C-code (dll/ctypes)
```

It looks like a spider web, and didn't think it would work, but maybe it does. Any comments?

Comment: The GIL allows you to run _only one Python thread_ at a given moment, and calling C code doesn't result in releasing the GIL.

Comment: This is in part why the multiprocessing library exists. It carries a thread-like API that allows you to write code that looks multi-threaded but is in fact leverage multiple processes to achieve true parallelism with your application.

Comment: I think what you should try to do is figure out what this 'freezing' is. And you haven't really described it, the entire machine? Your process? What do the various system indicators look like at the time of 'freezing'. What code does it happen in? Etc. Another thing you could try is use memory mapped io (`mmap`), for one thing, it might make your i/o fast enough as-is, for another, if it doesn't, you can use it to set up a shared memory buffer between your python process and a your C code that simply runs in a separate process.

Comment: Thanks pvg. Yes, that's part of the goal here - to get the C code to run on a separate process. Re:  freezing - even the picamera developers couldn't get around these random freezes. Likely the freezes have to do with kernel calls or periodic memory card access - which bottlnecks the writing to disk and somehow hangs for hundreds of miliseconds (or even seconds). Not sure I could do much more, especially when it comes to circumventing the OS/kernel issues.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that the "kernel calls or periodic memory card access" appear to be occurring independently of the python code, likely via OS issues. I've been advised to look into piCore or smaller linux kernels to save on overhead. I was hoping for a C solution - in the mean time.

Comment: Well, I would try `mmap` for starters for no other reason that the 'independently write from memory to disk' part is more or less what happens in that case. It's just that the C code in question is already written for you so you don't have to do anything.